# JavaScript/PHP: Get input from prompt and update the database

Tags: javascript, php, post, fullcalendar, prompt

The title of the selected event needs to be changed to whatever is inputted at the prompt.

But it is not working as expected.Please suggest/advice

### JavaScript function:

```
eventMouseover: function(event, domEvent) {
                var layer = '<div id="events-layer" class="fc-transparent" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; top:-1px; text-align:right; z-index:100"><a><img src="../../images/editbt.png" title="edit" width="14" id="edbut'+event.id+'" border="0" style="padding-right:3px; padding-top:2px;" /></a></div>';

                $("#edbut"+event.id).hide();
                $("#edbut"+event.id).fadeIn(300);
                $("#edbut"+event.id).click(function() {
                var title = prompt( '\n\nNew Event Title: ');
                if(title){
                $.ajax({
                url: '<?=base_url();?>testcalendar/fullcalendar/update_title.php',
                data: 'title='+ event.title+'&id='+ event.id ,
                type: "POST",
                });
                    }
                });
            },
```

### PHP form (update_title.php):

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
// connection to the database
try {
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blackboks-calendar', 'root', 'root');
 } catch(Exception $e) {
exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}
 // update the records
$sql = "UPDATE evenement SET title=". $title ."WHERE id=".$id;
$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$q->execute();
?>
```

Comment: where are you sending id? - at the moment you only have the title so your `WHERE` statement will be null / nothing

Comment: Is your JS function inside a PHP file? And try `"UPDATE evenement SET title='". $title ."' WHERE id=".$id;`

Comment: yes between <script type="text/javascript">
</script> tags

Comment: Try your SQL query? I think your probably is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is when you sending the title. It should be title not event.title

change

```
   data: 'title='+ event.title+'&id='+ event.id ,
```

to

```
    data: 'title='+ title+'&id='+ event.id ,
```

Comment: open console to see the request, params and response for the request in your browser.

Comment: That didnt fix it. But it helped:) and i found the answer it was only one "" in the update_title.php file.